# Function being called multiple times after the first time (Kendo Grid)

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I don't even know where to begin. I'm using Kendo Grid to list data sourced from a server. Everything is fine on first load including when I add additional functions and dom elements in the dataBound function. Calls to the server seemingly update (sync) the Grid just fine. BUT, it seems the dataBound function is called an additional time the second time round. Performing an on click function coded in the dataBound performs it a total of 4 times. How do I test for where the issue is and what do I need to destroy to stop this infuriating behaviour?

I don't even know what code to give you save for pasting in my whole website. What is the underlying theory behind this behaviour because there's obviously something I am fundamentally missing about how javascript, and therefore Kondo, works? How do I test for this, please. Thanks!

Comment: Start with your grid code and all related events which runs kendo methods or events.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution might be to use **[off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)** then on() in the databound e.g.

```
$(".cell").off("click").on("click", function(e){ ... });
```

this will get rid of previously attached handlers and ensure you only have one.

Even better, use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** outside of the Grid generating code.

```
$(document).on("click", ".cell", function(e) { ... });
```

With event delegation, the target of the event does not have to exist at the time the event handler is setup. In the example above, the click is on the document object which already exists, but the handler will only fire if an element with the class 'cell' is actually clicked. You can define this handler once in the document.ready before the grid is even created.